# IIS 6.0 programmatically - Problem creating virtual directories AND not setting it as a Application

Tags: c#, iis, iis-6

So I am creating a virtual directory in IIS  6.0 programmically, but I am following the only MSDN (or other) documentation on creating a virtual directory, but the documentation I have at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525598(VS.90).aspx

Is causing my virtual directory to be an application in IIS.  I was trying to use the metabase properties page:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cde669f1-5714-4159-af95-f334251c8cbd.mspx?mfr=true

But in the sea of options I am not sure what properties I need to set to stipulate it strictly as a virtual directory:

```
DirectoryEntries vdirs = site.Children;
DirectoryEntry newVDir = vdirs.Add(vDirName, (className.Replace("Service", "VirtualDir")));

newVDir.Properties["Path"][0] = phyPath;
newVDir.Properties["AccessScript"][0] = true;
newVDir.Properties["AppFriendlyName"][0] = vDirName;
newVDir.Properties["AppIsolated"][0] = "0";
newVDir.Properties["AppRoot"][0] = "/LM" + metaBaseFullPath.Substring(metaBaseFullPath.IndexOf("/", ("IIS://".Length)));

newVDir.CommitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `metabase.xml` file in `%systemroot%\windows\system32\inetsrv` is your best friend. If you create a virtual directory in IIS MMC you can see the requisite attributes attributes you need to set:

Here I created a virtual directory called `myvdir` in a site, this is the metabase configuration persisted to `metabase.xml`:

```
<IIsWebVirtualDir   
    Location ="/LM/W3SVC/1/root/myvdir"
    AccessFlags="AccessRead | AccessScript"
    DirBrowseFlags="DirBrowseShowDate | DirBrowseShowTime | 
                    DirBrowseShowSize | DirBrowseShowExtension | 
                    DirBrowseShowLongDate | EnableDefaultDoc"
    Path="D:\websites\myapp\www\myvdir" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **not** setting the app-pool specific entries.  so just:

```
newVDir.Properties["Path"][0] = phyPath;
newVDir.Properties["AccessScript"][0] = true;

newVDir.CommitChanges();
```

Haven't done this in awhile, but i think thats it

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, you cannot set an IIsWebVirtualDir to be an application (or not) by properties, but by calling methods on it. In your case you would have to call "AppDelete".

#### Make an IIsWebVirtualDir an application ...

```
newVDir.Invoke("AppCreate", 1);
```

or

```
newVDir.Invoke("AppCreate2", new object[] { 0 });
```

#### End an IIsWebVirtualDir being an application ...

```
newVDir.Invoke("AppDelete");
```

Details about these methods and their parameters can be found at the ADSI documentation, but you have to convert the code samples there to C# syntax.

- [MSDN: IISApp Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524878%28VS.90%29.aspx)
- [MSDN: IISApp2 Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525508%28VS.90%29.aspx)