# Changing local path in the default website of IIS through .NET code

Tags: c#, iis

I want to change Local path in the Home Directory tab of the Default Website in IIS, programmatically from the C# code.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? i dont think you are in the right way

Comment: I want to change the localpath that exists in the home directory tab of the iis

Comment: yeah I understood that , but what is you e scenarios which you need to deal with ? cause I really dont think you should do so( if possible ).

Comment: Actually I am doin a project which configures entire application in which I need to configure iis also and thats y i need to do it programatically

Comment: any reason you can't use something like MSDeploy? it will configure IIS, app pools, locations, vdirs, etc... MSDeploy walkthrough - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465322.aspx. Walkthrough using generated .cmd file - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356104.aspx

Comment: we can also change it using directory entry right??

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution, would be good to know how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at some articles and posts :

1. [Programmatically Manage IIS - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/server-management/DirectoryServicesIIS.aspx)
2. [How to Programmatically Modify the IIS Virtual Directory - MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/helloworld/archive/2009/05/29/how-to-programmatically-modify-the-iis-virtual-directory.aspx)
3. [Creating a new website programmatically on IIS using ASP.NET and C#](http://stweet.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/creating-a-new-website-programmatically-on-iis-using-asp-net/)
4. [IIS 6.0 programmatically - Problem creating virtual directories AND not setting it as a Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914097/iis-6-0-programmatically-problem-creating-virtual-directories-and-not-setting)
5. [Configuring IIS using Directory Services and C#](http://grounding.co.za/blogs/romiko/archive/2008/08/08/configuring-iis-using-wmi-and-c.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are managed APIs to deal with IIS, see John's asnwer here: [IIS API - Create virtual directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266026/iis-api-create-virtual-directories/266045#266045) for an example and also here: [Creating a new website programmatically on IIS using ASP.NET and C#](http://stweet.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/creating-a-new-website-programmatically-on-iis-using-asp-net/) the body of the method: CreateWebsite.

both are examples and should be adapted but a good starting point to show you how to interact with IIS from .NET / C#